# How to compare two version number strings in golang

Tags: go

I have two strings (they are actually version numbers and they could be any version numbers)

```
a := "1.05.00.0156"  
b := "1.0.221.9289"
```

I want to compare which one is bigger. How to do it in golang?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a nice solution from Hashicorp - https://github.com/hashicorp/go-version

```
import github.com/hashicorp/go-version
v1, err := version.NewVersion("1.2")
v2, err := version.NewVersion("1.5+metadata")
// Comparison example. There is also GreaterThan, Equal, and just
// a simple Compare that returns an int allowing easy >=, <=, etc.
if v1.LessThan(v2) {
    fmt.Printf("%s is less than %s", v1, v2)
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Some time ago I created a version comparison library: https://github.com/mcuadros/go-version

```
version.CompareSimple("1.05.00.0156", "1.0.221.9289")
//Returns: 1
```

Enjoy it!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Please don't take it down from GitHub anytime in the next decade :D

Comment: note that the library is now read-only and not maintaned actively (but seems like it could still work)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a general solution.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func VersionOrdinal(version string) string {
    // ISO/IEC 14651:2011
    const maxByte = 1<<8 - 1
    vo := make([]byte, 0, len(version)+8)
    j := -1
    for i := 0; i < len(version); i++ {
        b := version[i]
        if '0' > b || b > '9' {
            vo = append(vo, b)
            j = -1
            continue
        }
        if j == -1 {
            vo = append(vo, 0x00)
            j = len(vo) - 1
        }
        if vo[j] == 1 && vo[j+1] == '0' {
            vo[j+1] = b
            continue
        }
        if vo[j]+1 > maxByte {
            panic("VersionOrdinal: invalid version")
        }
        vo = append(vo, b)
        vo[j]++
    }
    return string(vo)
}

func main() {
    versions := []struct{ a, b string }{
        {"1.05.00.0156", "1.0.221.9289"},
        // Go versions
        {"1", "1.0.1"},
        {"1.0.1", "1.0.2"},
        {"1.0.2", "1.0.3"},
        {"1.0.3", "1.1"},
        {"1.1", "1.1.1"},
        {"1.1.1", "1.1.2"},
        {"1.1.2", "1.2"},
    }
    for _, version := range versions {
        a, b := VersionOrdinal(version.a), VersionOrdinal(version.b)
        switch {
        case a > b:
            fmt.Println(version.a, ">", version.b)
        case a < b:
            fmt.Println(version.a, "<", version.b)
        case a == b:
            fmt.Println(version.a, "=", version.b)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.05.00.0156 > 1.0.221.9289
1 < 1.0.1
1.0.1 < 1.0.2
1.0.2 < 1.0.3
1.0.3 < 1.1
1.1 < 1.1.1
1.1.1 < 1.1.2
1.1.2 < 1.2
```

Comment: All your test cases also succeed with the built-in strings.Compare(a, b). So I wonder if this was not the case in the past, or what else your extra effort is required for.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some of the libraries for version comparison:

1. https://github.com/blang/semver
2. https://github.com/Masterminds/semver
3. https://github.com/hashicorp/go-version
4. https://github.com/mcuadros/go-version

I have used ***blang/semver***.
Eg: https://play.golang.org/p/1zZvEjLSOAr

```go
 import github.com/blang/semver/v4
 
  v1, err := semver.Make("1.0.0-beta")
  v2, err := semver.Make("2.0.0-beta")
 
  // Options availabe
  v1.Compare(v2)  // Compare
  v1.LT(v2)       // LessThan
  v1.GT(v2)       // GreaterThan
```

Answer (score 4):

[go-semver](https://github.com/coreos/go-semver) is a [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) library for Go. It lets you parse and compare two semantic version strings.

Example:

```
vA := semver.New("1.2.3")
vB := semver.New("3.2.1")

fmt.Printf("%s < %s == %t\n", vA, vB, vA.LessThan(*vB))
```

Output:

> 1.2.3 < 3.2.1 == true

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what you mean by bigger.

A naive approach would be:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    a := strings.Split("1.05.00.0156", ".")
    b := strings.Split("1.0.221.9289", ".")
    for i, s := range a {
        var ai, bi int
        fmt.Sscanf(s, "%d", &ai)
        fmt.Sscanf(b[i], "%d", &bi)
        if ai > bi {
            fmt.Printf("%v is bigger than %v\n", a, b)
            break
        }
        if bi > ai {
            fmt.Printf("%v is bigger than %v\n", b, a)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/j0MtFcn44Z

Comment: For `a := strings.Split("1", "."); b := strings.Split("1.0.1", ".")`, two recent Go versions, the result is `[no output]`.

Comment: yeah as I said very naive version.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Jeremy Wall's answer:

```
  func compareVer(a, b string) (ret int) {
            as := strings.Split(a, ".")
            bs := strings.Split(b, ".")
            loopMax := len(bs)
            if len(as) > len(bs) {
                    loopMax = len(as)
            }
            for i := 0; i < loopMax; i++ { 
                    var x, y string
                    if len(as) > i {
                            x = as[i]
                    }
                    if len(bs) > i {
                            y = bs[i]
                    }
                    xi,_ := strconv.Atoi(x)
                    yi,_ := strconv.Atoi(y)
                    if xi > yi {
                            ret = -1
                    } else if xi < yi {
                            ret = 1
                    }
                    if ret != 0 {
                            break
                    }
            }       
            return 
    }
```

http://play.golang.org/p/AetJqvFc3B

Answer (score 1):

Striving for clarity and simplicity:

```
func intVer(v string) (int64, error) {
    sections := strings.Split(v, ".")
    intVerSection := func(v string, n int) string {
        if n < len(sections) {
            return fmt.Sprintf("%04s", sections[n])
        } else {
            return "0000"
        }
    }
    s := ""
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        s += intVerSection(v, i)
    }
    return strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
}

func main() {
    a := "3.045.98.0832"
    b := "087.2345"
    va, _ := intVer(a)
    vb, _ := intVer(b)
    fmt.Println(va<vb)
}
```

Comparing versions implies parsing so I believe these 2 steps should be separate to make it robust.

Answer (score 1):

tested in leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/compare-version-numbers/

```golang
func compareVersion(version1 string, version2 string) int {
    len1, len2, i, j := len(version1), len(version2), 0, 0
    for i < len1 || j < len2 {
        n1 := 0
        for i < len1 && '0' <= version1[i] && version1[i] <= '9' {
            n1 = n1 * 10 + int(version1[i] - '0')
            i++
        }
        n2 := 0
        for j < len2 && '0' <= version2[j] && version2[j] <= '9' {
            n2 = n2 * 10 + int(version2[j] - '0')
            j++
        }
        if n1 > n2 {
            return 1
        }
        if n1 < n2 {
            return -1
        }
        i, j = i+1, j+1
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)


func main() {
    j := ll("1.05.00.0156"  ,"1.0.221.9289")
   fmt.Println(j)
}


func ll(a,b string) int {
    var length ,r,l int = 0,0,0
    v1 := strings.Split(a,".")
    v2 := strings.Split(b,".")
    len1, len2 := len(v1), len(v2)

    length = len2
    if len1 > len2 {
       length = len1
    }

    for i:= 0;i<length;i++ {
        if i < len1 && i < len2 {
            if v1[i] == v2[i] {
                continue
            }
        }
        r = 0
        if i < len1 {
            if number, err := strconv.Atoi(v1[i]); err == nil {
                r = number
            }
        }

        l = 0
        if i < len2 {
            if number, err := strconv.Atoi(v2[i]); err == nil {
                l = number
            }
        }

        if r < l {
            return -1
        }else if r> l {
            return 1
        }
    }

    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee version strings have same format (i.e. SemVer), you can convert to int and compare int. Here is an implementation for sorting slices of SemVer:

```golang
    versions := []string{"1.0.10", "1.0.6", "1.0.9"}
    sort.Slice(versions[:], func(i, j int) bool {
        as := strings.Split(versions[i], ".")
        bs := strings.Split(versions[j], ".")
        if len(as) != len(bs) || len(as) != 3 {
            return versions[i] < versions[j]
        }

        ais := make([]int, len(as))
        bis := make([]int, len(bs))
        for i := range as {
            ais[i], _ = strconv.Atoi(as[i])
            bis[i], _ = strconv.Atoi(bs[i])
        }

        //X.Y.Z

        // If X and Y are the same, compare Z
        if ais[0] == bis[0] && ais[1] == bis[1] {
            return ais[2] < bis[2]
        }

        // If X is same, compare Y
        if ais[0] == bis[0] {
            return ais[1] < bis[1]
        }

        // Compare X
        return ais[0] < bis[0]
    })
    fmt.Println(versions)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution1

This is a version comparison that returns symbols to indicate the relationship between the two versions.

```
// If v1 > v2 return '>'
// If v1 < v2 return '<'
// Otherwise return '='
func CompareVersion(v1, v2 string) byte {
    v1Slice := strings.Split(v1, ".")
    v2Slice := strings.Split(v2, ".")

    var maxSize int
    { // Make them both the same size.
        if len(v1Slice) < len(v2Slice) {
            maxSize = len(v2Slice)
        } else {
            maxSize = len(v1Slice)
        }
    }

    v1NSlice := make([]int, maxSize)
    v2NSlice := make([]int, maxSize)
    {
        // Convert string to the int.
        for i := range v1Slice {
            v1NSlice[i], _ = strconv.Atoi(v1Slice[i])
        }

        for i := range v2Slice {
            v2NSlice[i], _ = strconv.Atoi(v2Slice[i])
        }
    }

    var result byte
    var v2Elem int
    for i, v1Elem := range v1NSlice {
        if result != '=' && result != 0 { // The previous comparison has got the answer already.
            return result
        }

        v2Elem = v2NSlice[i]

        if v1Elem > v2Elem {
            result = '>'
        } else if v1Elem < v2Elem {
            result = '<'
        } else {
            result = '='
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

<kbd>[go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/c1ioC_gS2Bl)</kbd>

### Solution2

This is another more straightforward approach.

```golang
CmpVer("1.01", "==", "1.001") // true
```

```golang
var (
    ErrInvalidOperator = errors.New("invalid operator")
)

func CmpVer(v1, op, v2 string) (bool, error) {
    v1Slice := strings.Split(v1, ".")
    v2Slice := strings.Split(v2, ".")

    var maxSize int
    // Let each other have the same length.
    if len(v1Slice) < len(v2Slice) {
        maxSize = len(v2Slice)
    } else {
        maxSize = len(v1Slice)
    }

    v1NSlice := make([]int, maxSize)
    v2NSlice := make([]int, maxSize)

    var err error
    // convert string to int
    for i := range v1Slice {
        v1NSlice[i], err = strconv.Atoi(v1Slice[i])
        if err != nil {
            return false, err
        }
    }
    for i := range v2Slice {
        v2NSlice[i], err = strconv.Atoi(v2Slice[i])
        if err != nil {
            return false, err
        }
    }

    var sign rune
    var v2Elem int
    for i, v1Elem := range v1NSlice {
        if sign != '=' && sign != 0 { //  // The previous comparison has got the answer already.
            break
        }

        v2Elem = v2NSlice[i]
        if v1Elem > v2Elem {
            sign = '>'
        } else if v1Elem < v2Elem {
            sign = '<'
        } else {
            sign = '='
        }
    }

    switch op {
    case ">":
        return sign == '>', nil
    case ">=":
        return sign == '>' || sign == '=', nil
    case "==":
        fallthrough
    case "=":
        return sign == '=', nil
    case "!=":
        return sign != '=', nil
    case "<":
        return sign == '<', nil
    case "<=":
        return sign == '<' || sign == '=', nil
    default:
        return false, fmt.Errorf("%w: %s", ErrInvalidOperator, op)
    }
}
```

<kbd>playground</kbd>

Answer (score -8):

Convert "1.05.00.0156" to "0001"+"0005"+"0000"+"0156", then to int64.

Convert "1.0.221.9289" to "0001"+"0000"+"0221"+"9289", then to int64.

Compare the two int64 values.

Try it on the <kbd>[Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/zj2UVDe78d)</kbd>

Comment: This will work as long as there are always the same number of digits in every version string. But if "2.o" is supposed to be greater than "1.9.8.6247" then it won't work. See my answer below for an approach that will work in that case.

Comment: For `a := "1.0.1"; b := "2.0"`, the result is `1.0.1 > 2.0`.

Comment: Among other issues, don't use `Sprintf` to make format strings when you can just use a `*` width! (i.e. replace your `Sprintf` madness with just `v += fmt.Sprintf("%0*s", width, value)`).

Comment: Addressing the comments by @JVK (`int64` vs `string` comparison), @peterSO ("2.0"), and myself (format strings) gives this: https://play.golang.org/p/I1uVOVR9DH (I'd personally use one of the other solutions here but the `"%%s%%0%ds"` format string stuff bothered me so I changed that).