# Is there a way to make Golang compilation fail if the compiler is only a point-release too old?

Tags: go

Specifically, for our next software release, I want to make sure to catch a bug fix that was released in go 1.5.2; is there a way to make the build fail if our build server tries to build my code using Go 1.5.1 or earlier?

I know about Build Constraints, and I can see how I can add a build constraint of "go1.5" to make sure the "1.5 or greater" compiler is used, but "go1.5.2" doesn't work (it appears that build tags go1.5.1 and go1.5.2 are not defined.)

On a related note, I also can't find a way to dump out the build tags that apply for a build, and yet this seems to be a pretty useful thing to do.

Comment: I'd keep looking in your build system for rules around this, that's where it belongs. If you can't figure out how to do it, you either don't understand the system well enough or it's not worth using as a build system.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal -- The build system is supposed to use the 'right tool' Agreed. The point of the go version build constraint is to make sure we don't build with the wrong major version. Why would this be any less legitimate a thing to do in the source code than requiring go1.5 vs go1.4 or linux vs darwin in a build tag? OR --  Suppose I want to release this on github and I know that it will crash if run on 1.5.1 - I can't control everybody else's build system, but I *can* make sure the code doesn't build on 1.5.1 by accident (and consequently nobody wastes my time with bug reports, etc.) :^)

Comment: The build tags are compiled into the binary, so there no way to dump them out after the fact. You could have a test or `init` that panics on the wrong `runtime.Version()`, to make it obvious the binary is broken.

Comment: sorry too late to edit, that should be "build tags are not compiled into the binary"

Comment: @JimB -- good thought about runtime.Version(); not as good as stopping the compile, but at least automated tests will fail, halting CI from attempting to deploy. Tnx

Comment: True, I do see some value in being able to tag the source so that the compiler throws and error telling the user they need a newer version for this project. Particularly in the case of an open source project. Still, that can easily be documented and if you're cloning and building someone else's project you should be reading that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-ldflags` to pass the configured min golang build and check at init() time if the runtime matches the specified version.

```
package main

import "runtime"

// go run -ldflags "-X main.minGoVersion=go1.5.1" main.go

// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409373/how-to-compare-two-version-number-strings-in-golang
func VersionOrdinal(version string) string {
    // ISO/IEC 14651:2011
    const maxByte = 1<<8 - 1
    vo := make([]byte, 0, len(version)+8)
    j := -1
    for i := 0; i < len(version); i++ {
        b := version[i]
        if '0' > b || b > '9' {
            vo = append(vo, b)
            j = -1
            continue
        }
        if j == -1 {
            vo = append(vo, 0x00)
            j = len(vo) - 1
        }
        if vo[j] == 1 && vo[j+1] == '0' {
            vo[j+1] = b
            continue
        }
        if vo[j]+1 > maxByte {
            panic("VersionOrdinal: invalid version")
        }
        vo = append(vo, b)
        vo[j]++
    }
    return string(vo)
}

var minGoVersion string

func init() {
    if minGoVersion == "" {
        panic("please pass  -ldflags \"-X main.minGoVersion=<version string> flag\"")
    }

    current := VersionOrdinal(runtime.Version())
    desired := VersionOrdinal(minGoVersion)
    if current < desired {
        panic("unsupported golang runtime " + current + " < " + desired)
    }
}

func main() {

}
```