# How to checkout latest release tag

Tags: git, go-git

I'm aware of how to checkout a specific commit or branch using `Checkout(&git.checkoutOptions)` with `plumbing.ReferenceName("<branchName>")` or `plumbing.Hash("<commit hash>")`, but I want to be able to clone a specific release version. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set ReferenceName in CloneOptions.

Example cloning v4.1 of git-go:

```
r, err := git.PlainClone("/tmp/foo", false, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL:      "https://github.com/go-git/go-git",
        ReferenceName: plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/tags/v4.1.0"),
        Progress: os.Stdout,
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any ideas around making this dynamic; e.g does go-git have any internals that will help me replace v4.1.0 with something like "latest", or will I have to save the latest release myself

Comment: If you don't set `ReferenceName` (remove that entire line), it will clone from master which should be latest

Comment: For this specific repo master is not what we want to access since it won't necessarily be the same as the latest release version. I want to be able to checkout the latest release version (which will have the latest tag) .

Comment: Given a repository with tags "alpha4" and "gamma7" and "v3.1", which is the latest? But: see [How to compare two version number strings in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18409373/1256452).